# What does the word “row” mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

TheFreedictionary.com says that the word "row" can mean: 3. A line of adjacent seats, as in a theater, auditorium, or classroom. or a. (chiefly Brit) a street, esp a narrow one lined with identical houses

which one is it in this context? (if any)

```
‘His wife a year he fondly loved
His wife a—a year he—fondly loved.’ 
Or suddenly waking up again:
‘Walking along the crowded row
He met the one he used to know.’
```

It is a translation of Russian, from  *[Crime and Punishment, chapter 1](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554-h/2554-h.htm#link2HCH0001)*. The original is "По Подьяческой пошел, // Свою прежнюю нашел."

Comment: Without knowing the source of the quote - apparently a poem - one can't be sure, but it seems likely that it's the 'street' meaning.

Comment: Worse than that, its a translation of Russian Poetry Crime and Punishment.  The original is "По Подьяческой пошел, // 
Свою прежнюю нашел."  Подьяческой seems to be the name of a narrow road in St Petersburg.  Perhaps it is famous for something in Russia.

Comment: In future please make sure that you **clearly identify the source** of any quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a very old word for narrow street/road. Some streets in the UK are still called ‘row’ though not many. For most English people it would sound very Dickensian.

Comment: There's some of those in the US as well, not sure if it's any more or less common.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means "narrow street".

The original is from Crime and Punishment, and a drunk man is singing drunkenly. "По Подьяческой пошел": literally something like "To Pod'yacheskoy, begone!".  "Pod'yacheskoy" is a narrow street in central St Petersburg.
Perhaps this is a fragment of a Russian bawdy song.

However the English suggests walking along a narrow but crowded street. A free interpretation in order to find a convenient rhyme.

Comment: Thank you for your answers :)